# How to ignore SIGKILL or force a process into 'D' sleep state?

Tags: python, c++, linux

I am trying to figure out how to get a process to ignore SIGKILL. The way I understand it, this isn't normally possible. My idea is to get a process into the 'D' state permanently. I want to do this for testing purposes (the corner case isn't really reproducible). I'm not sure this is possible programatically (I don't want to go damage hardware). I'm working in C++ and Python, but any language should be fine. I have root access.

I don't have any code to show because I don't know how to get started with this, or if it's even possible. Could I possibly set up a bad NFS and try reading from it?

Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate question; I didn't find anyone else trying to induce the D state.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get a process into the "D" state (uninterruptible sleep), you have to write kernel code which does that, and then call that code from user space via a system call.

In the Linux kernel, this is done by setting the current task state to uninterruptible, and invoking the scheduler:

```
set_current_state(TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE);
schedule();
```

Of course, these actions are normally wrapped with additional preparations so that the task has a way to wake up, such as registering on some wait queue or whatever.

Device drivers for low-latency devices such as mass storage use uninterruptible sleeps to simplify their logic. It should only be used when there is a sure-fire way that the process will wake up almost no matter what happens.

Kernel code to do little thing like performing an uninterruptible sleep can be put into a tiny module (start with a minimal driver skeleton) whose initialization function performs the code and then returns nonzero. You can then run the code using `insmod`, e.g.

```
 insmod my_uninterruptible_sleep_mod.ko
```

there is no need to `rmmod` because the function fails, and so the module is unloaded immediately.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to ignore `SIGKILL` or handle it in any way.

From `man sigaction`:

> The `sa_mask` field specified in `act` is not allowed to block `SIGKILL` or `SIGSTOP`.  Any attempt to do so will be silently ignored.

Comment: I would have said the same thing, no other way to put it, really.

Comment: Ok, I think my question's poorly worded. I thought a process in D state would not respond to SIGKILL until it changed state?

Comment: Your program cannot do anything with those signals. What the OS does is beyond your control.

Comment: @yourfavoriteprotein: But your process can't do anything in D state.

Comment: @DietrichEpp that's OK, I don't need it to do anything but be in D state. If that is not possible, I'll move on and work on something else.

Comment: @yourfavoriteprotein: Maybe you could write a kernel module, or even a FUSE filesystem, or something.

Comment: Create a system with very little RAM, but a very large SWAP (almost half of available disk space). Then make your process allocate almost all the virtual memory it can (to take up almost all of RAM and SWAP combined). Walk that memory, writing random values in it. Then, induce a core file. This will not cause permanent D state, but it will take a long time.

Comment: Thanks! I'll play around with this